# Просмотр логов в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Допустим логи хранятся в `frontend/runtime/logs/app.log`
Как эти логи можно просматривать иначе, кроме как в блокноте?
Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки, которые бы распарсивали этот файл и выдали в вебе эту информацию?

Comment: Доброе утро. Есть debug панель, в этой панели есть вкладка "log"

Comment: Это понятно. Но дебаг панель недоступна на продакшене.

Comment: Дебаг панель можно настроить под определённый ip, для других она не будет работать. Это первое. Второе, можно писать логи в базу, с очисткой раз в сутки, например, и из базы выводить в админке.